# How to test for an event to have been fired and its value?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai, eventemitter

I couldn't find any working examples to test for whether an event was emitted and whether the emitted value is as expected.

Here is the class that emits messages and its parent:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

class FileHandler extends EventEmitter {
            constructor() {
                super();
            }

            canHandle(filePath) {
                emit('not super type');
            }

            parseFile(filePath) {
                emit('supper parsing failed');
            }

            whoAmI() {
                return this.emit('who',"FileHandler");
            }
        }

module.exports = FileHandler;

//diff file

const FileHandler = require('./FileHandler');

class FileHandlerEstedamah extends FileHandler {
            constructor() {
                super();
            }

            canHandle(filePath) {
                this.emit('FH_check','fail, not my type');
            }

            parseFile(filePath) {
                this.emit('FH_parse','success');
            }
        }

module.exports = FileHandlerEstedamah;
```

Here is my current test code:

```
var sinon = require('sinon');
var chai = require('chai');

const FileHandlerEstedamah = require("../FileHandlerEstedamah");    

describe('FH_parse', function() {    
    it('should fire an FH_parse event', function(){
        const fhe = new FileHandlerEstedamah(); 
        var fhParseSpy = sinon.spy();
        fhe.on('FH_parse',fhParseSpy);       
        fhe.parseFile("path");

        //I tried a large number of variants of expect, assert, etc to no avail.
    });
});
```

I expected this to be straightforward but somehow I am missing something.

Thank you,
Jens

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . What is FileHandler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost nearly there. To check the value, we must call `done()` after that in mocha to tell that our test is finish.

The code

```
const chai = require('chai');
const assert = chai.assert;
const sinon = require('sinon');
const FileHandlerEstedamah = require("../FileHandlerEstedamah");

describe('FH_parse', function() {    
  it('should fire an FH_parse event', function(done){ // specify done here
      const fhe = new FileHandlerEstedamah(); 
      fhe.on('FH_parse', (data) => {
        assert.equal(data, 'success'); // check the value expectation here
        done(); // hey mocha, I'm finished with this test
      });       
      fhe.parseFile("path");      
  });
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This is working for me. I also like that the test is lean (without spies).

Comment: @jallmer glad to hear that 

Answer (score 2):

You can assert the spy was called once and called with expected arguments as below

```
sinon.assert.calledOnce(fhParseSpy);
sinon.assert.calledWith(fhParseSpy, 'success');
```